# How to determine operating mode of BJT transistor?

Tags: bjt

In the lab, I worked with this circuit:
[image]

I varied RL over a range of values and measured VC and VE. Then I got the IC values and plotted the results down below:
[image]

I am very confused as to how to know what mode my transistor is working in. Also, I do not understand why both plots look so different. Did I get the wrong data?

Comment: What's the difference between the two plots? Is it only the value of vcc?

Comment: Yes. It's either VCC = 15 V or VCC = 5V.

Comment: How did you measure collector current? Your Ic values don't match ohms law across \$R_L\$

Comment: For some interesting results, maintain at least 1 volt across emitter to collector.

Comment: Transistor saturation in your circuit occurs when the collector current increases to the point where the voltage drop across \$R_\text{L}\$ forces the collector voltage below the base voltage. It stays in active mode until then. To 1st order, compute your biasing pair's \$V_\text{TH}\$, assume \$\beta=\infty\$ so that \$V_\text{B}=V_\text{TH}\$, compute \$V_\text{E}\$ as a diode drop below \$V_\text{B}\$, and divide that voltage by \$R_\text{E}\$ for \$I_\text{E}=I_\text{C}\$. Multiply that by \$R_\text{L}\$ to get its drop, subtract it from \$V_\text{CC}\$ and compare to \$V_\text{TH}\$.

Comment: By the way, I think you really have a screwed up spreadsheet equation, somewhere. I can see that your values for the collector current are computed from an equation, not measured. There is consistency in the first chart and its list of collector currents. But this is not true for the list of collector currents for the bottom chart. Those are also obviously computed, but whacky. My guess is that 15 V is still in those equations rather than 5 V. -- Oh. Do you know what values are being used for R1, R2, and RE? I may be able to infer them, but if you know them it would be nice to have it stated.

Answer (score 1):

You will find this diagram interesting

[image]

You can generate the datapoints with this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1itMu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>